# Switch-Pitcher versus Switch-Batter

Tags: baseball, mlb

A Switch-Pitcher is pitching (Can pitch with the left or right arm).

A Switch-Batter is at the plate (Can bat from the left or right side).

In the MLB, who is forced to choose what side they are going to play from first (giving the other guy the advantage)?  And are they stuck on that side for the entire at-bat?

[Example Scenario](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2oD8KzxS14)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The pitcher must choose first, then the batter.  They are each allowed one change per plate appearance.

See [this wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_pitcher) for some background.